# Install Mega Sync Client on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Raspberry

Tags: apt, package-management, mate, raspberrypi

I have added the `deb http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Raspbian_8.0/ ./` package to my sources.list. But when I type `sudo apt-get install megasync` I get the error that the dependency `libcrypto++9`is **missing**.

- How can I install this library anyway?
- Is it really just not available or have they just 'forgotten' to add it to the appropriate repo? I've seen it's available for all sorts of things even PowerPC. So it must be somewhere around for a raspberry configuration? So how can I install it?
- Which repo do I have to add or manually install a .deb-package?

Comment: I think the problem is you've added the repository for Rasbian_8.0, which probably has libcrypto++9 available. In Ubuntu 16.04, the package name is [libcrypto++9v5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libcrypto%2B%2B9&searchon=names). Unfortunately, Mega doesn't have armf packages for Ubuntu.

Comment: well that's too bad. Do you may know another cloudprovider that gets supported on armhf devices? I wanna use it for making backups automatically